# How to fix api call working in browser but 403 in android studio

Tags: android, api, kotlin, debugging, retrofit

Hi i'm wondering why my API call works in browser but when called in Android studio I get a 403 error.
The Debug

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 403 https://api.boblop.com/search/api/rest/v3/catalog/products/search/keyword?q=asesea&key=esaesaesae (106ms)
D/OkHttp: server: AkamaiGHost
D/OkHttp: mime-version: 1.0
D/OkHttp: content-type: text/html
D/OkHttp: content-length: 350
D/OkHttp: expires: Tue, 20 Sep 2022 10:27:24 GMT
D/OkHttp: date: Tue, 20 Sep 2022 10:27:24 GMT
D/OkHttp: strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
D/OkHttp: <HTML><HEAD>
D/OkHttp: <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
D/OkHttp: </HEAD><BODY>
D/OkHttp: <H1>Access Denied</H1>

Any Ideas why android studio might be giving me back a 403 error?
Many Thanks
```

Comment: share some code snippet which you have tried so far.

Comment: i think there are some issue while passing key inside URL. just try to print it on log. or you can pass it a a constant variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just implement it in some code you can check it below:

```
 request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://api.johnlewis.com/search/api/rest/v2/catalog/products/search/keyword?q=dishwasher&key=AIzaSyDD_6O5gUgC4tRW5f9kxC0_76XRC8W7_mI")
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache")
                    .addHeader("User-Agent",System.getProperty("http.agent"))
                    .build();
```

by using above code i am able to get 200 response in mobile app. i used OkttpClient for this just add header in retrofit to solve 403 issue.

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.johnlewis.com/search/api/rest/v2/catalog/products/search/keyword?q=dishwasher&key=AIzaSyDD_6O5gUgC4tRW5f9kxC0_76XRC8W7_mI}
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to 401, but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic (like an incorrect password).

Comment: so you think theres no way to go around the forbidden area?

Comment: need to authenticate.

Comment: how would you go around to authenticate it in android studio though?

Comment: It is necessary to examine the relevant service. It has its own methods. Interceptors can be used.